# How can I change key/name of Amazon S3 object using REST or SOAP?

Tags: rest, soap, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

How can I change **key/name** of Amazon S3 object using REST or SOAP?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to rename an object is to copy the old object to a new object, and set the new name on the new copy.

The REST call you need is detailed [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html).

Syntax

```
PUT /destinationObject HTTP/1.1
Host: destinationBucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-copy-source: /source_bucket/sourceObject
x-amz-metadata-directive: metadata_directive
x-amz-copy-source-if-match: etag
x-amz-copy-source-if-none-match: etag
x-amz-copy-source-if-unmodified-since: time_stamp
x-amz-copy-source-if-modified-since: time_stamp
<request metadata>
Authorization: signatureValue
Date: date
```

> This implementation of the PUT operation creates a copy of an object
>   that is already stored in Amazon S3. A PUT copy operation is the same
>   as performing a GET and then a PUT. Adding the request header,
>   x-amz-copy-source, makes the PUT operation copy the source object into
>   the destination bucket.

Keep in mind the existing ACLs, however:

> When copying an object, you can preserve most of the metadata
>   (default) or specify new metadata. However, the ACL is not preserved
>   and is set to private for the user making the request.